# Woocommerce price on attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have problem with WooCommerce. I have two attributes - 5 sizes and 10 colors (total 500 product variations). Price is based only on sizes (for colors it does not matter).

How can I config product variations prices of a variable product without editing 500 on them?

For example:

`RED S = 10$
RED XL = 15$
GREEN S = 10$
GREEN XL = 15$`

Comment: add the color to variation product

Comment: I have it. But now i must edit 500 variables and change prices. I want to change price only for size ex. S = 10$ and auto generate variables ex. RED S = 10.

Comment: What you can do but is not very easy, is to have your color attribute with only a unique value. Then you will hide  it with CSS . Then you will add a custom field selector with your color values *(or something else like swatches with some jQuery code)* Then you will add to cart that custom color value and you will replace the color attribute unique value by the custom field selected color. That is possible, but it needs some work.

Comment: I think that you don't understand me (sorry for my english). Woocommerce engine to generate variations is good for me, it works. But after that i must click every variation and add price manually. I have over 500 records to click for one product. It will take me hours for multiple products. What i want to do, is add price automatically, by setting price only for size attributes (only 5 clicks). But i don't have idea how to do this. I don't belive that woocommerce users who have over 100 products and multiple attributes, are making this manually. It will take them a few weeks.

Comment: I want also similar.. like I set value for each attribute and then generate variation with its value buy woocommerce create all variation button from all attribute

Answer (score 2):

Might want to try this, https://wordpress.org/plugins/markup-by-attribute-for-woocommerce/

I had the same issue where one of my customers has 54 variations on dozens of products. Half of those variations add anywhere from $1.00 to $15.00 to the price of the product. Editing and calculating the price on every single one of those was a major pain. I ended up writing a plugin to do it.